# can't connect on minio with node js

Tags: node.js, minio

- i tried to connect on minio with node js using minioClient
- this is my code

**Minio.js**

```
const Minio = require('minio')
const minioClient = new Minio.Client({
   endPoint: 'xxxxxx',
   port: 9000,
   useSSL: true,
   accessKey: 'xxxxxx',
   secretKey: 'xxxx'
});

module.exports = minioClient
```

**fileupload.js**

```
const minioClient = require('../config/connection/Minio')
module.exports = minioUpload = {
    upload: async(req, res) => {

        if (req.file) {
            var metaData = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                'X-Amz-Meta-Testing': 1234,
                'example': 5678
            }

            var originalname = req.file.originalname.split(' ');
            const fileName = originalname.join('_');
            try {

                // Using fPutObject API upload your file to the bucket maztou.
                minioClient.putObject('maztou', fileName, req.file.buffer, metaData, function(err, etag) {
                    if (err) return console.log(err)
                    return res.status(201).json('File uploaded successfully.', fileName)
                });
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err, '<== ERROR');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**router.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const minioUpload = require('../controllers/fileupload')
const router = express.Router()
const multer = require('multer')
router.route('/uploads').post(multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() }).single("file"), minioUpload.upload)

module.exports = router
```

And the server return this :

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT XXXX:9000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  errno: -60,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'XXXX',
  port: 9000
}
```

Can some one help me for this issus, i'have already read all the documentation about minioClient , all my setup is good, and i have. this issus !

Comment: Can you check if your request can get list of buckets or not? if no you may not have right credential - if yes - you may not have right header.

Comment: is this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The timeout indicates that the client cannot connect to the server. You should check if the endpoint, port and credentials passed to MinIO client are correct and turn off `useSSL` if TLS is not enabled. If your MinIO server is running in docker, you may want to check if the port is exposed.